# Using Navigation Drawer in Mater Detail Flow Template

Tags: android

How can i use the following code in a ItemListActivity.java file in my Master detail Template using Eclipse and Android SDK. 
Since this page code originally have one oncreate bundle code, and later it have one for two pane code....

```
final String[] data ={"one","two","three"};
final String[] fragments ={
        "org.arthakrantipratishthan.arthakranti.CommunityFragment",
        "org.arthakrantipratishthan.arthakranti.PagesFragment",
        "org.arthakrantipratishthan.arthakranti.HomeFragment"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_list);

     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);

     final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
     final ListView navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
     navList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: You can get the full original code while creating a Master Detail Template in eclispe or else just tell me how to have Navigation Drawer in ItemListActivity.java class